# Is there an event being triggered after the page was updated/rendered as a result of the DOM update?

Tags: javascript

In the context of a javascript + html + css dynamic web page, is there a way to detect the completion of the page update (including the load of images) as a result of a DOM change?

NOTE: I'm not lookgin for the events like `"load", "DOMContentLoaded", "readystatechange"`, as these are only triggered during the page load, which is not relevant for my scenario.

Thanks

```
document.addEventListener("<some event>", function(event) {
    console.log('==Updated====');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For general page updates you could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log("DOM updated");
});

observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
  childList: true, // adding or removing nodes
  characterData: true, // text changes
  attributes: true, // attribute changes
  subtree: true // descendant nodes
});
```

Observing DOM updates this way can be expensive, so make sure to only use options that you need. Also the callback passed to `MutationObserver` should be performant because it gets executed frequently.

For loading images, there is a [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/load_event) event which fires when the image has been loaded. Something like this would work:

```js
const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {
  console.log("image loaded");
};
image.src = "https://example.test/1.jpg";
```

Please note that `load` event doesn't buble, so you would need to add event listeners to individual images.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was much preferring to have a dedicated event for all these, triggered once. Cause instead of having to deal with the observer implications, I can set up a setTimeout() and put my logic in there, but is actuallt this continuous check that I want to get rid of.